# How to mount large LVM image on ubuntu 14.04 on root?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, lvm, mount

I am running ubuntu 14.04.03 and need to mount thinly provisioned lvm volumes for glusterfs to the system. I did this first by adding them to /home/glusterfs/dir, this worked as /home has 120G of space and the LVM image just 20G.

Now I thought it might be better to mount to /bricks/brick1/dir - this has caused unexpeced problems as now root is filled to 100% and the system does not boot again.

Is it not possible to mount a seperate image to / without filling up the space?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly I was mistaken. After a reboot, the filesystem in question did not mount to the mountpoint and I did not realize this before doign a rsync on the mount point. This resulted in a filled up file system as the intended LVM volume was not mounted. The solution was just to delete the directory.

Answer (score -1):

Glusterfs is a virtual fs, as far as i remember - it stores data in files in the underlying fs. So yes, if you want to mount glusterfs on some directory - make sure tha underlying partition is big enough.

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem with thin provisioning. You can pretend you have as much space as you want and it works great. Up until you actually use all the space and things fall over. The actual space is what is important, not the thin volume size.

You are free to mount additional file systems at /bricks/brick1 or wherever you want. This isolates problems if it fills up.